# Microsoft Word - Keyboard Shortcuts for changing font?

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a word doc which has a tabbed-column list and I want to change some text in one column (single words) to use a different font. At the moment I double-click a word to highlight it then click the dropdown, scroll down to Consolas,etc. etc. and it takes forever.
Is there a keyboard shortcut to change a font to my most recently selected?

> concat -----  join two or more arrays together
>
> indexOf ----- find an item in the array and returns its index

EDIT: Sorry guys I had to dash off (boss kept me talking). Would somebody care to explain the downvote?
It's Word 2013.

I don't know of the keyboard shortcuts in Word for this - that's what I'm asking.

I didn't realise macros were still around in Word, thought it was only Excel. Certainly nothing obvious in the menu "ribbon".

EDIT: Found it under "Views"  [Macros for Dummies](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-make-a-macro-in-word-2013.html)

Comment: What version of Word? I'm pretty sure newer versions save your used fonts at the top of the font list. I don't know of a keyboard shortcut but you could type the font name in that dropbox to save some time. Another strategy is to mark the words with a * or something and come back later and do all the words at once, then delete the * with a find and replace.

Comment: Did you look a the Word keyboard shortcut list yet?  If one doesn't exist, then make a macro and assign a key to it; that's what they're there for. ;)

Comment: As a note, if you're going to be doing this frequently, it might make sense to make it a custom formatting/style (which can be assigned shortcut keys, i.e. ctrl-alt-1 being assigned to Heading 1).  This has the added advantage that if you decide to change things later, all instances can be updated at once, rather than having to hunt them down and find individual uses of a specific font . . .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**From memory**, no "Word" available

Find the option to "Record a macro" <del>, close to it you should might find "use relative references" (uhh... or is that Excel only?) click it so that it is active - if it is there</del>.

- Make sure the cursor is in position to do one replacement
- Click on "Record macro"
- Options to define a keyboard short and more appears (edit: added)
- Slowly do the steps you need to fulfill your task
- Click "Stop recording"

<del>SOMEWHERE in that sequence you will be able to define a shortcut key for the macro you just recorded.</del>

In recording: Avoid using the **mouse** for cursor movements and selections. Select by holding either of the SHIFT keys AND moving the cursor by the arrow-keys (CTRL+Arrow for full words), as you have one word selected - use the mouse to set the font, deselect by MOVING the cursor - just back/forth if you do not have anything more meaningful. You may also be able to reposition the cursor IN PREPARATION for a repeated run on NEXT word - before you stop recording.

If you're successful with the repositioning of the cursor - then the entire process might end upp be to repeatedly launch the macro with the shortcut key.

Comment: Thanks! Good tip on the cursor movement. I used this guide: http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-make-a-macro-in-word-2013.pageCd-storyboard,pageNum-3.html

Comment: =) nice one with images and all... I'm using Excel too much ;-)

Comment: To reach the Macro function, do `[View] > Macros` and select "Record". Alternatively use keyboard shortcut `ALT + F8`.

Answer (score 3):

The <kbd>Alt</kbd> key shortcuts may be another good option here - [a few are listed here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/keyboard-shortcuts-in-word-95ef89dd-7142-4b50-afb2-f762f663ceb2#bkmk_ribbonwin) under "Use the Access Keys for ribbon tabs", but there are additional levels within the ribbon that aren't listed. Granted, it doesn't quite go straight to the most recently selected font, but you can type the font name in question out, which I find to be faster than scrolling and doesn't require any use of the mouse.

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> (pressed sequentially - you don't have to hold any down at the same time) will select the Home tab in the ribbon and then highlight the Font field - from there, enter whatever font you want to switch to.

Comment: Also check out [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-or-run-a-macro-c6b99036-905c-49a6-818a-dfb98b7c3c9c?ns=winword&version=90&syslcid=1033&uilcid=1033&appver=zwd900&helpid=46&ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us)

Answer (score 1):

I have tested this answer on Word 2016. The [source](http://www.ddmcomputing.com/word/keys/wdsk06.htm) where I found it was published in 2004, for I'd imagine it would work for intermediate versions as well. (Note that this answers the question in the title, not the body. i.e. this is the hotkey to change font in general, not to the most recently selected.)

1. (Optional) Select text which font you want to change (using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+Arrow).
2. Open the font select menu with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>.
3. Choose the new font name. If text was selected, it will be converted to the new font. If not, you will start typing in the new font.